# Installing Ubuntu now, or wait for 14.04?

Tags: uefi, lts

So, I really like to try out Ubuntu, because I would like to use something new on my computer. Now, I have got a UEFI based motherboard with secure boot enabled. (An Asus B85M-G) But my question is, should I attemp to install Ubuntu now ? Or should I wait for the 14.04 ?

Thanks already for answsering

PS: Does my motherboard support Ubuntu properly ?

Comment: Easy way to test: install it.

Comment: Of course thats a way to install it... But my question is if I better wait until 14.04, if that is easier to install it on a uefi system.

Comment: Can you wait until it's released?

Comment: Of course I can wait. I was just asking, that's all.

Comment: Right, so, I don't really want opinions, but I rather have a answer of what I should do or not. I rather as well have a answer from a expert person then from someone else who doesn't really have that much experience. I just don't want to do anything wrong.

Comment: What you should do or not is entirely up to you. Why you need us to tell you what to do?

Comment: Uhm... I mean it different. I don't order you or anything like that. And please, since I made this thread you keep posting useless things and it feels like you're acting a bit annoying towards me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the difference between a long-term support (LTS) release, which is what 14.04 is, and a non-LTS release, is more important than the possibility of improved EFI support in 14.04. This is very graphically illustrated [here:](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)

[image: LTS releases will be supported for MUCH longer than non-LTS releases]

As you can see, 13.10 will become unsupported *this year* (in July, to be precise), so you'll have to upgrade before then or be cut off from updates (including security fixes). Note that there's no overlap between end-of-life (EOL) for 13.10 and the release of 14.10, so you'll have to either upgrade to the 14.04LTS or go without updates for about three months.

It used to be that non-LTS releases got about a year and a half of support, but that was cut in half with 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with UEFI.  Instead of worrying about whether or not to install 14.04, you could just install the final beta version found here: http://mirror.cse.ucdavis.edu/releases.ubuntu.com//trusty/

Then just update as updates become available.  Usually the final beta version is pretty stable.  Or you could just install 13.10 and update when 14.04 drops.  I think you are safe either way.

Answer (score -1):

I would install 13.10, then update to 14.04 when it's available. I don't know of any disadvantages of running the update. For me I wouldn't want to wait around two weeks.